# How is it possible for me to use "ToArray<T>()" on a variable of type "IEnumerable<out T>"

Tags: c#

After saving an anonymous type into a variable of type "IEnumerable" using LINQ, I discovered that it is possible to use several methods that were defined inside of the class "Enumerable" over the aforementioned variable. How is this possible? It should also be noted that "IEnumerable" is an interface.

Here is a small code example:

```
class MyClass
{
    public string Name;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass[] myArray = 
        { 
            new MyClass{Name = "Bill"}, 
            new MyClass{Name = "Bill"},
            new MyClass{Name = "Steve"}
        };

        IEnumerable<MyClass> variable = from myInstance in myArray
                                        where myInstance.Name == "Bill"
                                        select myInstance;

        MyClass[] newArray = variable.ToArray<MyClass>(); // How is it possible for me to use "ToArray<T>()" on "varialble"?
    }


}
```

Comment: I use ToList : (from myInstance in myArray
                                        where myInstance.Name == "Bill"
                                        select myInstance).ToList();

Comment: All the LINQ methods (that work with `IEnumerable<out T>`) are [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

Comment: `IEnumerable` is an interface that allows enumeration. All that `ToArray()` does is enumerate that `IEnumerable` and create a new array containing all enumerated values. What exactly about this feels weird for you or don't you understand?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045242/this-in-function-parameter

Comment: add `using System.Linq;`(`ToArray()` is an extension method) and now you will be able to do `var MyArray = variable.ToArray();`

Comment: Jon Skeet did an interesting series of blogs about how Linq works. [Here's how he reimplemented `ToArray()`](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/02/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-24-toarray/) - it's worth a read.

Comment: When you ask "how is this possible," do you mean "how can I call methods that aren't part of the interface" (i.e. "how to extension methods work") or "how do I get it to work?" The comments indicate to me that your real question is not clear.

Comment: [List<T>(IEnumerable<T>) MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8#constructors) Not sure I understand the question, but check the `List` docs for `ToArray()`

Answer (score 1):

This uses a C# feature called [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods). The method is defined in a separate class (hence the name - it extends the functionality of the original class/interface). The first parameter is prefixed by the `this` keyword, and the method can be called as if it's a method on that parameter (i.e. on your `IEnumerable<MyClass>`).

In your example, you are using a library called LINQ, which is composed entirely of extension methods. You can see the source code for `ToArray` [on github](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/17b97365645da62cf8a49444d979f94a59bbb155/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L942). Your code will have `using System.Linq;` at the top, which is what allows you to call the method in your code.