# How does static extension work for js interop in Blazor?

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-5, blazor-jsinterop

I have managed to make such peace of code.

Blazor html:

```
@inject IJSRuntime js
<button @onclick="Delete">Delete</button>
```

Function Delete():

```
private async Task Delete()
    {
        var confirmed = await js.Confirm($"Are you sure you want to delete?");
    }
```

Static extension:

```
    public static class IJSRuntimeExtensionMethods
    {
        public static async ValueTask<bool> Confirm(this IJSRuntime js, string message)
        {
            return await js.InvokeAsync<bool>("confirm", message);
        }
    }
```

This code makes javascript confirmation pop up.

My question is how does it work?

Most confusing part is:

```
var confirmed = await js.Confirm($"Are you sure you want to delete?");
```

**Why we can just write `Confirm`, but not `IJSRuntimeExtensionMethodsInstance.Confirm`?


Why we also need in this bit `js.`? 


How is it passed through `js.Confirm($"Are you sure you want to delete?")` to the static extension or what dot notation is exactly doing here after `js`?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["this" in function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045242/this-in-function-parameter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extension methods are a language feature, that allows you to extend the behavior of any class or interface. Basically this is just syntactic sugar to simplify the call to a static method and make it look like a call to an instance method.

In the declaration of the extension method note the `this` before `IJSRuntime js`. This means the method *extends*  the `IJSRuntime` type:

```cs
public static async ValueTask<bool> Confirm(this IJSRuntime js, string message)
```

Under the hood the call to

```cs
js.Confirm("text");
```

gets translated to

```cs
IJSRuntimeExtensionMethodsInstance.Confirm(js, "text");
```

and you could also call the method like this!